# Difficulty of getting image from public S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use S3 to store user uploaded images. Some images like profile pictures and other thumbnails should be visible to anyone. However, I also want to have some images to be visible to users in the group that the image was "posted" to.

My app will handle all of the logic to decide whether or not a certain user has access to the image.

My question is: with a public S3 bucket and my app controlling the visibility of the images, how hard would it potentially be for someone to see images that they generally don't have access to?

Is there a better way to set up an S3 bucket to meet these requirements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is:

- Do not grant public access to *any* of the images/objects in Amazon S3
- Your application at all times determines whether they should be allowed access
- For users who are allowed access to an image, create an **Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL**, which is a time-limited URL that will grant access to the object.

Your application can generate the pre-signed URL in a couple of lines of code, without requiring a call to AWS.

This way, all your security is maintained by the application rather than having to selectively make some objects public and there is no way for people to gain unauthorized access to objects.